# Ошибка вывода с БД: Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in

Tags: php, mysql

```
$id = $_GET['id'];

$zhkk='zhk-id';

$zkhrow = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM zhk where $zhkk="$id"');

$zkh = mysql_fetch_array($zkhrow); // 44 строка 



echo $zkh[0];
```

Результат:

> Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in (путь) on line 44

Comment: Понимаю, что проблема в $zhkk='$id' , но $id  выводил , всё верно,  $zhkk -данный столбец есть в БД

Comment: насколько я понимаю столбец то имеет имя `zhk-id` а не `$zhkk`.. тогда в такие же лапки как айди возьмите

Comment: Исправил на $zkhrow = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM zhk where 'zhk-id'='$id'"); Ошибка исчезла, но ничего не выводит:   print_r($zkh);

Answer (score 2):

Необходимо было в наименование столбца указать следующие кавычки `, при одинарной стандартной кавычке не работало!

Рабочий запрос:

```
$zkhrow = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM zhk where `zhk-id`='$id'"); // работает!
```

Comment: потому что надо изучить в начале основы языка, да ..... http://php.net/manual/ru/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax

Comment: в одинарных кавычках подставление значений переменной не работает просто. вот и все.. поэтому я и написал такой комент в топе

Comment: Не знаю смол ли я донести смысл так как данная ` кавычка не отображается на сайте когда обрамляешь её в текст.  Хорошо, так в чём разница между ` кавычкой и ' такой?